# How to use direct connection applications behind a kerberos proxy

Tags: proxy, kerberos

I have a corporate proxy using Squid and kerberos for authentication, the proxy is configured for standard use, I.E allow http, https, a few others and block everything else. Now, there are many applications that support basic proxy authentication, but do not support Kerberos based authentication and many others that connect directly to the internet. I used Proxifier before the upgrade to kerberos to make my applications use the proxy, but I cannot do so now. I then installed an application called PX to create a proxy that connects to kerberos, but the proxy it creates is a simple HTTP Proxy and proxifier doesn't work correctly with it. Anyone has a setup for a situation like this?. I use Windows 10 and I obviously don't have access to the server where squid is configured. The application I need to connect to the internet uses standard https ports, it's not a torrent application nor anything that uses the ports blocked by squid. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, for this particular case I've found the following setup to solve 99% of my problems.

First get Px here https://github.com/genotrance/px

Next get Fiddler: http://www.getfiddler.com/dl/Fiddler4BetaSetup.exe

Configure PX with your user and your domain and run it. By default it creates a running proxy on 127.0.0.1:3128

Configure your sistem proxy to use the proxy supplied by PX.

Execute fiddler, it should create ANOTHER proxy at 127.0.0.1:8888

Use this proxy in your apps. Proxifier should work as well.

Why use fiddler and not the direct 127.0.0.1:3128?, PX creates a pure http proxy and fiddler allows to tunnel https and connect request through it.

Any requests will pass through fiddler which will redirect them to the PX proxy which will redirect them to the squid proxy (So expect very slow speeds).

In the end since you're just redirecting your apps towards your proxy, if your proxy bans using regex expressions or direct IP connections some apps will NOT work, and in these cases using TOR or a VPN is the only real solution. Hope it helps someone avoid all the headaches I went through.

Comment: Why not just use Fiddler - Under Rules click 'Automatically Authenticate' then enable proxy under Options | Connections.